# Drupal 8 - How to Reference Flags Twig Template without showing full content?

Tags: theming, 8, flags

I'm using Drupal 8 to construct a page, where flags are required for *Adding Videos to Favorites.* I am using the ***Flags Module***, but it's a custom template, so I didn't use the {{content}} reference directly. Instead I'm using the machine names of each field in displaying and styling the node. I reference them using {{content.field_*fieldname*}}

The problem is that I'm unable to reference the flags that I have created using the Flags Module. They are appearing on other basic pages and articles (when I turn on those areas while editing the flags), but they fail to appear in the custom template that I have created for a node.

Could anyone please help me with this? Any sort of help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is it a part of links still? So `content.links`? If not you'll need to enable devel and dump out the variables to see what the name is.

Comment: @Kevin how do you mean it's part of links? Do I create a field under the Flag? I tried content.links and it's not showing up.

Comment: You'd need to identify then what the variable name is within the content array using a debugger.

Comment: Thank you very much @Kevin - I'll use a debugger. I've already switched on Twig debug but it's not showing the variable names. Can you suggest one?

Comment: Twig debug won't do that. You need to use devel or a debugger like xdebug and optionally Twig XDebug. devel comes with functions to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**FOUND IT**

Alright guys, so it's simple.

You reference the flag this way in your Twig Templates:

```
{{ content.flag_machinename }}
```

Cheers.